# Error referring static variable inside static function in a class in PHP 7.4.2

Tags: php, xampp

I am learning PHP and using PHP 7.4.2 (using XAMPP) version to try out examples. I am trying to access the static variable from a static function using self::$vaiablename

But getting the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'self' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\php-getting-started\classes\CountryRepository.php on line 18


<?php

require 'Country.php';
require 'State.php';

class CountryRepository {
    private static $countries = array();

    protected static function init() {
        $countries = array();
        array_push($countries,
        new Country('Austria','at',array(new State('Styria'), new State('Burgandy'))));
        array_push($countries,
        new Country('United States','usa',array(new State('California'), new State('Maryland'))));
        array_push($countries,
        new Country('Luxembourg','lu'))

        self::$countries = $countries;
    }

    public static function getCountries() {
        if(count(self::$countries) === 0) {
            self::init();
        }
        return self::$countries;
    }
}

?>
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: You need to show us a bit more than the error message - please show the relevant code.

Comment: i have updated with the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

In your case there is a missing semicolon after the last `array_push`. PHP interprets this as `array_push()self` which leads to the above error.

```
new Country('Luxembourg', 'lu'))
                                ^^^
```

vs

```
new Country('Luxembourg', 'lu'));
                                ^^^
```